# Where is entity_model => sales/quote? from eav_entity_type table

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, eav

I think magento saving all **eav entity** information From `eav_entity_type` table. But where is `sales/quote` entity information?

This `eav_entity_type` `attribute_id` is linked with `eav_attribute` table right?

Where is `sales/quote` entity information?

Could you please explain me In-detail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All type id information is mapped in the database table `eav_entity_type`:

[image]

The problem you're describing is, however, that sales order and quote information have not been EAV since ~1.4 or so. So therefore there is no entity type in later versions of Magento. Instead, all Sales Quote information is accessed directly as a Magento Resource Model which maps directly to a table. In this case, the table is `sales_flat_quote`; which may optionally have a prefix if you've defined a prefix.

Comment: k thank you for information. could you please describe about `attribute_model` or let me know the best `eav model` ref.. link expect http://excellencemagentoblog.com